# How do I use underscore to check for "undefined" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
if(typeof hello! = 'undefined'){

}
```

This is too hard to type, would like to use underscore

Comment: Did you take two seconds to [search here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+underscore+check+for+undefined)? Yikes.

Comment: `hello === undefined` should work well, even without underscore .. but in many cases I find - and design code such that - a simple "false-y" conditional is correct: `if (!hello) ..` The only reason to use `typeof` here is 1) for global variables, which may not exist (ick, prefer `window.prop` to avoid ReferenceErrors!) or 2) over paranoia about `undefined` being "redefined".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [the official documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined), you can use `_.isUndefined()`:

```
_.isUndefined(window.missingVariable);
=> true
```

Comment: It seems this only works for object properties, but not for local vars: ```_.isUndefined(hello)
=> Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined(…)``` (Tested in Chrome 52)

Comment: Local variables can be checked if they're first declared: `var a; _.isUndefined(a);` Attempting to access an undeclared variable will always throw a ReferenceError unless checked via `typeof a === "undefined"`. However, this question was about how to check for undefined via Underscore.js.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?  http://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined

```
_.isUndefined(value)
```